# Entity framework two-way relationship not loading includes

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, breeze

This is making me feel like an idiot. Entity Framework is supposed to be fairly simple, yet I can't sort this out myself and clearly I've got a fundamental misunderstanding. I hope it doesn't turn out to be an idiot-question - sorry if it is.

Three code-first objects, related to one another.

```
public class Schedule
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Charge> Charges { get; set; }
}

public class Charge
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

When I query this, I want all related types, so:

```
        Schedule currentSchedule = _Context.Schedules
                .Include("Charges.Type")
                .Where(cs => cs.Start < dateWindow && cs.End > dateWindow)
                .First();
```

In C#, this has been working fine.

The problem arises because we're not stopping at C#, but passing the data onto a javascript library called Breeze with smooths out data operations at the client end. Breeze has a bug/feature which demands that EF relationships between objects be specified at BOTH ENDS. So when I do my query above, I don't end up with any Types, because their relationship with Charge isn't directly specified.

So I change it to this:

```
public class Type
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public virtual Charge Charge { get; set; }
}
```

Because virtual is a navigation property, so that should enable Breeze should now to go both ways across the relationship without changing the data structure. But EF doesn't like this. It tells me:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Core.Charge' and 'Core.Type'. The principal end of this
>   association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations

Fair enough. I can see how this could be confusing. Now, my understanding is that if you define a foreign key in a dependent class, it has to be that classes' primary key. So we change it to:

```
public class Type
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Charge"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public virtual Charge Charge { get; set; }
}
```

And that seems to work but ... it's stopped loading any Type information when you ask for a schedule. Messing around with the includes doesn't seem to do anything at all.

What's going on, and what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't only added a navigation property (`Type.Charge`) to an existing model/relationship. Instead you have changed the relationship completely from a one-to-many to a one-to-one relationship because by default if a relationship has only one navigation property EF assumes a one-to-many relationship. With your change you have configured a one-to-one relationship.

Those relationships have different foreign keys: The original one-to-many relationship has a separate foreign key in the `Charge` table (probably named `Type_RowId` or similar). Your new relationship has the foreign key at the other side in table `Type` and it is the primary key `RowId`. The `Charge`s you are loading together with the `Schedule` probably don't have any related `Type` with the same primary key, hence no `Type` is loaded.

If you actually want to reproduce the old (one-to-many) relationship with just a navigation property at the other side you must add a collection to `Type` instead of a single reference:

```
public class Type
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Charge> Charges { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: OK, my understanding is completely off kilter. I had assumed that if neither end was specified as a collection, EF would produce a one-to-one relationship - that was all that's needed here between Charge and Type. Back to the documentation.

Comment: @MattThrower: One-to-one would mean that no two `Charge`s can have the same `Type`. Is that the case in your business logic?

Comment: not inside the same schedule, no. A schedule has a number of charges, each one of which must be a different type. Type is in a separate table from Charge only because it's used elsewhere, otherwise they could be part of the same object.

Comment: @MattThrower: But if `Charge1` is in `Schedule1` and `Charge2` is *in another* `Schedule` those two charges are allowed to have the same type? If yes, you definitly cannot use a one-to-one relationship between `Charge` and `Type`. It must be one-to-many. The restriction that the carges' types inside a single schedule must be unique is application business logic and you can't ensure this with any mapping configuration.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. Have a tick. I'm sure this seemed easier when I used to draw it out in SQL. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly it's fixed EF but seems to have broken Breeze again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to put ForeignKey on RowId, I think you may want to define some relationship like this

```
public class Type
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public int ChargeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ChargeId")]
    public virtual Charge Charge { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. What would you call the key though? "ChargeId" isn't the name of any property in the model. Tried both "Charge" and "RowId" - both result in the "Unable to determine the principal end of an association" error again.

Comment: you can define the key name in the Type model.